# KendoUI DatePicker Set Value culture dd/MM/yyyy only works fine es-AR and not es-CL

Tags: kendo-ui, formatting, globalization, culture, kendo-datepicker

I have a issue and lost 3 days... I using the Globalization in Kendo UI.

- I have read several times http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization and apply in my web proyect.
- I use **ASP.NET MVC**. **Framework 4**. Visual Studio **2010**. **Kendo UI 2014.2.1008**
- My country is Chile. I should be use es-CL for culture and es-ES for UICulture (spanish messages for pageable, filterable, etc).
- I need that my whole app works as dd/MM/yyyy independent of client PC Windows culture is set.
- I set the kendo.culture.es-CL.min.js as a copy of kendo.culture.es-AR.min.js, It was a copy & paste, it was the only thing I could think to do :(
- I have a Partial View in header with the load of culture and others, it load first other views:

@{

```
var culture =  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString();  //se obtiene del servidor (web.config)
var cultureUI = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.ToString();  //textos de mensajes kendo, paginación, filtros, etc, se obtiene del servidor (web.config)
}
```

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.2.1008/messages/kendo.messages." + cultureUI + ".min.js")"></script>

<script>
kendo.culture("@culture");
</script>
```

- I have a controller HomeController a Test Action:

  ```
  public ActionResult Test(DateTime fechaTermino)
  {
    ViewBag.FechaTermino = fechaTermino;
    return View();
  }
  ```
- Then, I have a View "Test" (after load the previus View), I set my DatePicker:

  @{
  var fechaTermino = (DateTime)ViewBag.FechaTermino;
  }

  ...

  @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
   .Name("mdpTermino")
   .Value(fechaTermino)
  )
- I set the culture in my web.config to es-CL and not works! (see picture, appear dd-MM-yyyy)

  < globalization uiCulture="es-ES" culture="es-CL"  / >
- I change the culture to es-AR and its works!! (appear dd/MM/yyyy) why? 
  I have both js files in my Kendo folder in my solution.

  < globalization uiCulture="es-ES" culture="es-AR"  / >
- I Try put format in every DatePiker how see in this example use HTML 5 /JS (I use MVC mode):

http://dojo.telerik.com/UqON

It's is very slowly, I don't like change 20 DatePikers everytime, and I put in my DatePiker:

```
.Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

and don't work using es-CL. It continue showing dd-MM-yyyy, ignores the format!!

Why only that es-AR works and not es-CL?
[image: Error In set es-CL culture KendoUI, only works es-AR for dd/MM/yyyy]